# static library maximum file size generated by Visual Studio or other limitations?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

are there some limitations under Visual Studio (2008, 2010, ...), in particular for C++ big projects ?

I think of limitations like :
- a maximum number of files for a project to be compiled / linked
- a maximum .lib file size that can be generated

We are working with quite big projects, so we would like to prevent any futur problem.
For example we already had problem with too big .obj files, that we managed to correct thanks to the Visual Studio /bigobj flag.

Thanks.

Comment: It is limited by available memory, usually the linker falls over first.  Around half a gig is the typical critical size.  Otherwise solved with the 64-bit toolset, your patience will fall over first.

Comment: Do you mean that a static library of 500 Mb is a critical size for a 32 bit system ?

Comment: No, the 32-bit version of link.exe

Comment: What is the actual problem? There are always limitations... but which limitation is affecting you?

Comment: The problem is that I am working on a VS solution which contain a big project of hundred of files. This project generate a static library which grow very fast. At the moment its size is about 1 Gb. I would like to avoid being blocked by that or by too many files in a same project for example

Comment: One limit we hit every few half-years is the `/Zm` in some projects http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bdscwf1c.aspx I've seen "unity-build" on a very huge monster project with more than 2000 compilation units in VS2008 and it worked! On "unity-build" I mean including every .cpp files into a single unity.cpp and compiling the whole stuff as a single unit by compiling unity.cpp. Note that there was a very huge problem with this, the compilation wasn't faster/better - if you organize includes well and use precompiled headers well then VC++ compiles extremely quickly anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Your real problem is not that you don't know the various size limitations of your toolset. The problem is that you don't have a plan about how to react when/if you hit some of these limitations. I have two suggestions.

First is to split up a huge monolithic static library into pieces; this is a generic solution to any of the limitations you've mentioned. A giant slab of object code is already evidence enough to question whether there's good abstraction within the code base. Libraries in Visual Studio can contain references to other libraries that are automatically incorporated at link time, so there's no technical reason that mandates a single huge library.

Second is that you don't appear to have any automatic testing that indicates when you have a problem. One kind of automatic test would be to compare file sizes and the number of exposed symbols (for example) against policy limits. If a policy limit is exceeded, it should generate a warning and a message to someone with authority to mandate action about it. Another kind of automatic test would be a test program that links against every entry point (or at least most of them) and ensures that your code is actually linking.

My second suggestion, though, is moot if you address the first one.

Comment: I agree with this answer. Having monolithic libraries is a problem for most languages, even .NET. The solution should definitely be to break the static library up into smaller libraries. This may take some time but anything else is just a temporary band-aid. One good place to start is to draw up the dependencies in a dependency layer diagram. Doxygen can create such diagrams, alternatively use a CASE tool such as Sparx Systems "Enterprise Architect".

Comment: Well I agree with you but it will be such a work to split a monolithic library that I am looking for a strong argument in order to convince the management. A limitation of Visual Studio could have been a good argument...

Comment: @oaimac It's still a good argument. If you don't split in advance of hitting a tool limitation, you'll be faced with a more-or-less complete work stoppage, basically without advance notice, and it will take far longer than anybody wants to get the build working again. During this time, much of the programming staff will be blocked, unable to work. The argument to management needs to be couched in terms of schedule risk. Knowing the particular limitations won't help all that much; at best you'll be able to predict when you hit the wall.